# Strange GIF artifacts when uploading to Behance

Tags: animation, gif, behance

I'm getting these weird effects when I upload GIFs to Behance.

Here is the GIF, on stack.imgur:

[image]

Here is a screencap of what it looks like on Behance:

[image]

The trails don't appear in the upload preview or when uploaded elsewhere. So this problem is somehow specific to Behance, but I haven't been able to find anything on the net about it, and I haven't seen it anywhere else.

Does anyone know what to do about this?

Comment: I suspect additional compression is being added when it's uploaded to Behance. One way to confirm this is to compare the file size of your original GIF with the GIF used in the page.

Comment: Looks more like an overly-aggressive GIF optimisation algorithm to me: one which is forcing no re-rendering of unchanged pixels - resulting in trails for the changed pixels. One approach is to do the GIF optimisation yourself to get within their target upload parameters, and see if their algorithm can be sidestepped by uploading already-optimised GIFs -

Comment: - another approach would be to be super-careful that the background blue falls within ***their*** colour palette from their final GIF (sample the blue in the trails behind the stars in the behance-auto-optimised GIF and *use* ***that blue*** for the blue of the overall star-field), and yet another approach might be to post these somewhere where you have more control over image uploads, and then link to those versus uploading to Behance.