# Strange gif-compression on Behance

Tags: gif, behance

There is a strange thing, when I upload a gif to a Behance project: it appears perfectly at the preview, but goes wrong after publishing. It seems, Behance makes some kind of compression during publishing, however the published gifs have bigger size, then the original ones.

The original one:

[image: original]

and after publishing:

[image: published]

Can you please help me solving this?

Comment: I know there are no answer but the same question was [asked here](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/68956/strange-gif-artifacts-on-behance). I'm guessing Behance just run some not-very-nice compression on GIFs.